# How to fix autolayout in .xib file for iphone 5 4-inch screen

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, interface-builder, iphone-5

First I would like to say please to not give me a link to a tutorial to http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display

becuase he is using storyboards which is not useful since I am using a .xib file.

Also, this tutorial that everyone gives me does not help me fix my problem either:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

I am only writing this because everytime I post this question everyone doesn't read it correctly and just gives me the above two links. So the following is my problem:
I have made my .xib project an autolayout project and when I switch from 3.5 to 4.0 inch screen it works perfectly fine. However, when I actually run the application it does not work.
Here is a link to the folder for the project if you could help by opening the project in xcode: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0XkO0WuCozjd0lPcGUzNGpfY0E&usp=sharing

This is a picture of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in xib
select view then select  identify andType and Deselect Use Autolayout 
like this
[image]

Comment: @chaiguy what problem occur ?

Comment: Sorry I was just having an awful time figuring out autolayout. Didn't mean to detract from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Click on utilities  and then click on file inspector .... and then uncheck the **Use AutoLayout**.And after doing that check that what is your xib size. If it's iPhone4 size 
    then in

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad

    {
        appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

        if (appDelegate.window.bounds.size.height > 548)/// this is for iphone5

        {
          // Again set the position of all the acc to iPhone 5

         }
        else

          {
           // it will work for iphone 4
          }
     }
```